# Good RSS news feed for JavaFx news and resources

Tags: javafx, rss, feed

...Yes I've seen:

[Best Resources for Learning JavaFX?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/116519/best-resources-for-learning-javafx)

but it doesn't really answer the question. Maybe there just aren't any good resources at the moment?

UPDATE:

http://developers.sun.com/rss/javafx.xml is OK

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- If you have Google Reader you could use their Discover tool to find feeds, e.g. [JavaFX feeds](http://www.google.com/reader/view/#directory-search/javafx/).
- Technorati has a [large selection](http://www.technorati.com/search/javafx?authority=n&language=en)
- Google Blog Search also has [some results](http://blogsearch.google.com/blogsearch?hl=en&ie=UTF-8&q=javafx&btnG=Search+Blogs).

Note that I don't even know what JavaFX *is* - your best bet, as with any topic, is to use the social search tools out there to find authors who write about your particular topic, and then subscribe to them if you like what you read.

Something I've taken to recently is using [Google Alerts](http://www.google.com/alerts/) and Google Reader (any RSS reader will do) to get reports as they come in of searches for a particular topic. You get access to what people are searching for within a topic and what they eventually decide on. I've discovered a few interesting pages on PHP since I started this, it's a useful tool.